# Change BibTeX output formatting?

Tags: bibtex, formatting

I am using the bibliography style "plain", which in a Technical Report, formats "Technical report" in roman font.  However, my publishers want "Technical Report" to be capitalised, and in italics.  How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I missed something but can't you hack the default `plain.bst` file (that you would put in your current working directory or a known tex directory), or directly use [makebst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/)?

Comment: I probably could - if I knew how... But I'm running out of time and can't afford the time to learn how to do it right now.  I was hoping somebody could simply tell me what to do!

Comment: Done it!  In the block `FUNCTION {format.tr.number}` I changed `{ "Technical Report" }` to `{ "{\em Technical Report}" }`.

Comment: You mean you just want `\em` or `\em` + small caps? For the former, you can run `latex makebst`, follows the default options but when comes `TECHNICAL REPORT NUMBER:` choose `i` (`Tech. report and number italic as {\it Tech. Rep. 123'}`) -- that will update `FUNCTION {techreport} {...}` with a line looking like `format.tr.number emphasize output.nonnull`.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer and accept it, to help others searching the site.

Answer (score 1):

(Originally posted as a comment by Alasdair)

Done it! In the block `FUNCTION {format.tr.number}` I changed `{ "Technical Report" }` to `{ "{\em Technical Report}" }`.